# why cant I use XNOR on type "std_logic_vector" ?

Tags: vhdl

it seems straightforward but I cant get past it

```
            din : in std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
            sin : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            .
            .
            .

            if ( din(idx downto idx-3) XNOR sin(3 downto 0) ) then
```

and I get the

> ** Error: Z:/lab_dig_2/1/prep/additionalQ/additionalQ.vhd(30): Type error resolving infix expression "xnor" as type std.STANDARD.BOOLEAN.

error

is there a special operator for vectors? I remember that std_logic_vector is a perfect type for this kind of operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xnor` in your expression operates on two `std_logic_vector` type and thus returns another `std_logic_vector` type, but the `if` expression expects a `boolean` type.

You may want to change the expression to the below, if you want a condition that is true when the `xnor` result is not all zeros:

```
if (din(idx downto idx-3) XNOR sin(3 downto 0)) /= "0000" then
```

**EDIT: More information about implicit type convert in VHDL-2008**

VHDL is a strong typed language where the designer typically has to do explicit
type casts so the result matches the required type, and otherwise an error is
generated.

However, VHDL-2008 has added some implicit type casting, in special with the
condition operator `??` which can convert to `boolean` type.  The operator is
declared in `std_logic_1164` system package as:

```
function "??" (l : std_ulogic) return boolean;
```

The condition operation is automatically applied for `if`, `elsif`, `until`,
`assert`, and similar places if the expression did not evaluate to a `boolean`
type.  So, if you are using VHDL-2008, then it is possible to write:

```
signal test_sl : std_logic;
...
if test_sl then
  ...
```

Whereby the condition operator `??` is implicitly applied, as if written:

```
if ?? test_sl then
```

An equivalent to the below, which is also valid in VHDL-2002:

```
if (test_sl = '1') or (test_sl = 'H') then
```

The `??` operator is only declared in standard VHDL-2008 for `std_ulogic` type,
which thus also applies to `std_logic` type.  However, the operator can be
overloaded in a user declared function to apply for `std_logic_vector`, with:

```
-- Or operation of ?? for all elements in arg
function "??" (arg : std_ulogic_vector) return boolean is
  variable res_v : boolean;
begin
  res_v := FALSE;
  for idx in arg'range loop
    res_v := res_v or (?? arg(idx));
  end loop;
  return res_v;
end function;
```

If the above is declared, then it is possible to use implicit casting of
`std_logic_vector` to boolean in `if` statements, like:

```
signal test_slv : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
...
if test_slv then
  ....
```

Or even:

```
if din(idx downto idx-3) XNOR sin(3 downto 0) then
```

A word of caution though, since the code may be become less readable to others
and thus more error prone, if such tricks are used; but it is possible.

Comment: nice trick, thanks. I was wondering? why cant I use a typecast like command/operator? (my C is rusty...but thats how I would have approached it)

Comment: @YNWA: because VHDL's mindset is completely the opposite of C.  It is strongly typed, and strives very hard to not make assumptions, and force the author of the code to specify what they want to happen.  So there are no assumptions like "all bits zero is the same as false" for example.  If you want C-like foot-shooting opportunities, you'll find [Verilog over there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verilog) :)

Comment: @YNWA: You can find some additional information about type casting added to the answer above, which also supplements Martin Thompson comment about strong typed language.

Comment: fantastic. we wont be using VHDL '08 though, but good for the future. thanks!